# Function With a Finite Sequence As the Domain?

Tags: functions

Here is a prime example of what I have in mind: The prime counting function, $\pi(x)$, is such that $\pi(1)=0, \pi(2)=1, \pi(3)=\pi(4)=2$. So can I write this function as $\pi$ of (each member of the finite sequence $3,4$) equals $2$? Likewise, when $x=5$ or $6$, the function is $3$. Can this be expressed as $\pi(5\; \text{or}\; 6) = 3$?

When the function is the same for more than one sequential value for $x$, can each of these values for x be included in the domain together? For example, $\pi(7,8,9,10)= 4$. This would be one mathematical expression instead of four separate ones - $\pi(7)=4, \pi(8)=4, \pi(9)=4$ and $\pi(10)=4$.

Comment: This is too much unclear.The prime counting function is very popular, but what exactly do you want with this function? If possible, give some example.

Comment: Considering the cases of x=7, x=8, x=9, and x=10, when the function is 4 for each of these sequential values for x, I want to express in a single function that pi of each of these is 4. It would be something like this: pi(7,8,9,10)=4

Answer (score 2):

In your example, looks like you want the [preimage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)#Inverse_image) (or inverse image) of $4$. Which is $$\pi^{-1}(4) = \{ 7,8,9,10\}.$$

The preimage gives you the elements in the domain whose image is $4$. But do not make confusion here, the preimage is a set, not a function. In more precise terms, for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have the following.
$$\pi^{-1}(n) = \{ x\in \mathbb{N}: \ \pi(x) = n \}$$

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [step function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StepFunction.html) with an infinite number of intervals $P_i=[p_i,\infty)$. Then define $\pi(n)=\sum_\limits{j,n\in p_j} 1$.

More generally, you could use $f(\{x\in[a,b]|x\in\mathbb{Z}\})=y$, but you are in danger of merely shifting definitions around.